# Ambiguous match while using cucumber step definitions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, cucumber

Need some help in getting rid of this error. Not able to pass this step with cucumber.

```
 And I fill in "Email" with "a1@test.com"               # features/developer_registration.feature:9
      Ambiguous match of "I fill in "Email" with "a1@test.com"":

      features/step_definitions/developer_steps.rb:9:in `/^I fill in "(.*?)" with "(.*?)"$/'
      features/step_definitions/developer_steps.rb:31:in `/^I fill in "(.*?)" with "(.*?)"$/'
```

THe part in steps.rb which deals with this step.

```
When(/^I fill in "(.*?)" with "(.*?)"$/) do |email, password|


  fill_in "a1@test.com", with: email # express the regexp above with the code you wish you had
  fill_in "1", with: password

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified the code as below and it worked as required.

```
When(/^I fill in Email with "(.*?)"$/) do |email|
  fill_in "EMAIL", with: email # express the regexp above with the code you wish you had
end
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the output you have the same step defined. Once on line 9 and the other on line 31. You only showed one of those definitions.

Check the two definitions on those lines and you will likely find the source of your problem.